# YAML Linter for Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

Tags: yaml, visual-studio-2019

The Visual Studio builtin yaml linter is not catching all errors. Is there a command I need to run to get it to validate the document? Currently, it seems to be working with intellisense.

Comment: A general YAML linter can only syntax-check your document. Validation requires knowledge of the target structure, which can only be provided by whatever consumes the YAML (since YAML does not have a schema language like e.g. XML).

Comment: Good point Flyx. Thank you. When working with Azure pipelines, is it best to just run you pipeline in azure to test it?

Comment: Thank you both for your response. Is there a way to test in azure pipelines without committing my work in progress to a code repository? I am trying to reduce the number of meaningless commits. Also, I am working with templates, so I would like something where I can browse the files (these can be in a repository. I just don't want to save my work in progress)

Comment: There seems to be a [server-side API](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/34#issuecomment-584253286) for it, although I don't know Azure and can't really make much sense of it.